# Google maps .gm-style div now displays as block, thus breaking the map

Tags: google

recently my Wordpress page with Google Maps started displaying markers in an odd fashion- look!

[image]

The problem is- Google changed they code and added this baby into the code:

```
  .gm-style div {
    display: block;
    }
```

Overriding the code with, let's say, `display:inline-block !important;` doesn't work, since a new display:block is being automatically generated by Google! (Picture below)
[image]

The site itself is here if anyone wants a peek:

```
`http://objekt.ee/properties/?lease=rent&view=map`
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

find this in file: `/wp-content/themes/rentbuy/js/scripts.js`

```
<div class="overlay-simple-marker"
```

… and replace it with:

```
<span class="overlay-simple-marker"
```

Comment: That did it! People layed minuses on you yet they couldn't answer the question themselves. I guess replacing div with span isn't semantically very correct, but it didn't break anything and solved the problem! Many thanks, friend! I added +1 but you're still with -1 :/

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to fix this problem is to define a version in you api call, e.g.:

```
<script src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
```